# How to search for words in a string in a text file?

Tags: c++

I am trying to match words from user input with a string from a text file.

When this code runs, it crashes after the file is opened. (marked by ****)
How can I change it to properly match the strings from user input with strings from the text file.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
const int Size = 81;                // 80 characters for the line + 1               for the '\0'
const int MaxNumberOfWords = 10;

int main() {
  char input[81], temp[81], fin[81];
  printf("Input a string\n");
  fgets(input, 81, stdin);
  int len = strlen(input);


  char *div;
  div = strtok(input, " ");
  while (div != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n",div);
    div = strtok(NULL, " ");
    
    
    ifstream inStream;                          // declare an input stream for my use
    char theWords[ MaxNumberOfWords][ Size];    // Array to store words from input line
    int wordRow = 0;                            // Row for the current word
    char wordToLookup[ Size];                   // word to lookup
    bool wordWasFound = false;                  // flag to track whether or not word is found
    char c;                                     // stores return character after input
    
    inStream.open( "C:\\Users\\dqiao4\\Desktop\\Dev-Cpp\\dictionaryMax6.txt");
    assert( ! inStream.fail() );  // make sure file open was OK
    
    
    //*****this is where the code crashes
    while ( inStream >> theWords[ wordRow]) {
      wordRow++;
    }
    
    

    for (int i=0; i<wordRow; i++)  {
      // See if this word matches
      if ( strcmp( div, theWords[ i]) == 0 ){
        wordWasFound = true;
        break;      // quit looking
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: But what is your *specific* question? If you are looking for someone to write the code for you then you have come to the wrong place. Please attempt to write the code yourself. If after genuine effort you still have difficulties then show your code and ask a *specific* question.

Comment: SO doesn't work like that .... do something yourself first..

Comment: I posted a picture of the code i did

Comment: @thedude Pictures of code are highly discouraged. How are we supposed to copy and paste this into our on IDEs?

Comment: You declare a constant, but then ignore it and use magic numbers everywhere?

Comment: @thedude C or C++? You will also get very different answers depending on which language you choose.

Comment: Don't post code as images. And you still haven't asked a question. What is it you need help with?

Comment: This code is clearly C++, so I removed the C tag.

Comment: Suggest you do some basic debugging in a debugger and/or with debug print statements. An obvious starting point that is likely to help is to examine the value of  `wordRow`. No prizes for guessing what you will find.

Answer (score -1):

int main() {

```
char input[81];int i=0,j=0,k=0;
cout<<"Input a string ";
while(i<=80){
 input[i]=getch();
 cout<<input[i];
 if(input[i]=='.')
 break;      
 i++;
}
ifstream File("C:\\User\\New.txt");
string line;
if(File)
{   
    while(getline(File, line))
    {
        char buff[1024];
        strcpy(buff, line.c_str());
        while(j<35){
            k=0;
          while(k<i){
            if(buff[j]==input[k])
            {
                int j1=j,k1=k;
                while(true){
                  if(buff[j1]==input[k1])
                    {
                        if(input[j1]=='.'){
                            cout<<"match";
                            return 0;
                        }   
                        j1++;k1++;
                    }
                    else
                    break;
                }
          }k++; 
         }j++; 
        cout<<endl;  
    }
}
```

}
}

Answer (score -1):

```
#inlude <sstream>
#include <string>
```

in your source and read the text file in string stream buffer, convert it to string and do

```
auto pos = file_in_str.find("word_to_find");
```

That pos is the the starting index of word in file